# Allow Coupon only for customers with certain domain in email?

Tags: cart, discount, coupon, promotions

How can I check, when a coupon is being applied, if the customer's email is from a certain domain?

**Here is the module code based on Raphael's code**

```
<?php
class NA_LimitCoupon_Model_Observer 
{
    protected $_domainsAllowed = array(array('COUPON1', 'email1.com'), 
                                       array('COUPON2', 'email2.com')
                                      );

    public function validate(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {

$timestamp = date("m-d-Y H:i:s");
$msg = "Timestamp:".$timestamp;
$fp = fopen("/var/tmp/".__FUNCTION__.".txt", 'a');
fwrite($fp, $msg . "\n");
fclose($fp);

        try 
        {
            $this->validateRestriction($observer);
        }
        catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) 
        {
            Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception $e) 
        {
            Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError($this->__('Cannot apply the coupon code.'));
            Mage::logException($e);
        }
    }


    public function validateRestriction(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $errMsg = false;
        // Get the quote: 
        $quote = $event->getQuote();
        // obtain the code being used
        $code = $quote()->getCouponCode();
        // Get the current quote email
        $currentEmail = $quote()->getCustomer()->getEmail();
        $explodedEmail = explode('@', $currentEmail);

        // Get the domain from the email address
        $domain = array_pop($explodedEmail);

$timestamp = date("m-d-Y H:i:s");
$msg = "Timestamp:".$timestamp."\nCode: ".$code."\nCurrentEmail: ".$currentEmail."\nDomain: ".$domain;
$fp = fopen("/var/tmp/".__FUNCTION__.".txt", 'a');
fwrite($fp, $msg . "\n");
fclose($fp);

        switch($code) 
        {
            case 'COUPON1':
                // check if the email address is in the COUPON1 domain        
                if ($domain !== $this->_domainsAllowed[$code]) 
                {
                   // Wrong domain
                   $errMsg = 'This coupon code is restricted to customers of email1 company';
                }
                break;
            case 'COUPON2':
                // check if the email address is in the COUPON1 domain        
                if ($domain !== $this->_domainsAllowed[$code]) 
                {
                   // Wrong domain
                   $errMsg = 'This coupon code is restricted to customers of email2 company';
                }
                break;
        }
        // handle errors
        if ($errMsg) 
        {
            Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError($errMsg);
            $quote->setCouponCode('');
            $quote->collectTotals()->save();
        }
    }
}
```

Wondering if this will work as designed. I want to limit use of certain codes for certain email  domains.

**And the XML file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <LimitCoupon>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </LimitCoupon>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <module>
                <class>LimitCoupon_Model</class>
            </module>
        </models>
        <events>
            <salesrule_validator_process>
                <observers>
                    <LimitCoupon_validate>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>module/observer</class>
                        <method>validate</method>
                    </LimitCoupon_validate>
                </observers>
            </salesrule_validator_process>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

Comment: You could use 'salesrule_validator_process' event (but it will works only for logged in user) or Ajax request on checkout page(but it will be more complicated).

Comment: You could add this as an answer here @SeStro.

Comment: All people using codes are logged in. Can you show me how to do this?

Comment: @SeStro, can you show how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're referring to Magento 1, you can create a module for that.

`app/code/local/Vendor/Module/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Vendor_Module>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Vendor_Module>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <module>
                <class>Vendor_Module_Model</class>
            </module>
        </models>
        <events>
            <salesrule_validator_process>
                <observers>
                    <vendor_module_validate>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>module/observer</class>
                        <method>validate</method>
                    </vendor_module_validate>
                </observers>
            </salesrule_validator_process>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

Then in `app/code/local/Vendor/Module/Model/Observer.php`

```
<?php

class Vendor_Module_Model_Observer
{
    protected $_domainsAllowed = array('domain.com');

    public function validate(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        try {
            $this->validateRestriction($observer);
        }
        catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError($this->__('Cannot apply the coupon code.'));
            Mage::logException($e);
        }
    }


    public function validateRestriction(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $errMsg = false;

        // Get the current quote email
        $currentEmail = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote()->getCustomer()->getEmail();

        $explodedEmail = explode('@', $currentEmail);
        $domain = array_pop($explodedEmail);

        if ( ! in_array($domain, $this->_domainsAllowed)) {
           // Wrond domain
           $errMsg = 'This coupon code is restricted to another customer email domain';
        }

        // handle errors
        if ($errMsg) {
            Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError($errMsg);
            if ($code = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote()->getCouponCode()) {
                $observer->getEvent()->getQuote()->setCouponCode('');
            }
        }
    }

}
```

In this file, you'll have to change the following with the domain name you need. Please note that you can add more domains by adding more entries to this array:

```
protected $_domainsAllowed = array('domain.com');
```

Comment: Raphael, where does the variable `$code` on line 40 in the observer get set?

Comment: Yes, it is Magento 1.4.0.1, see above for my module code.

Comment: @MB34 well it is set on line 40 ^^ it is not used so you can probably do `if ($observer->getEvent()->getQuote()->getCouponCode())` instead ;)

Comment: Raphael, I'm not getting anything from the module code posted above. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @MB34 well I dunno it's hard to tell are you sure your observer is called ?

Comment: Apparently not because I don't get anything written to `/var/tmp` as my `fwrite()` is supposed to be doing. I edited source above showing the `fwrite()`s

Comment: Any more ideas Raphael?

Comment: @MB34 no I'm out of ideas here

Comment: Do the XML files look correct?

Comment: Made adjustments to the XML and a couple of other tweeks to the code and it is working...Thanks a bunch.